# Update trigger on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to create a trigger on update. I have two tables source and destination with same table structure. So I want the records to be updated on destination when there is an update on source. I tried the below trigger function:

```
  Create FUNCTION ins_functiontest() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
 IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
     INSERT INTO  destination(id,name,tg_op)
     VALUES (new.id,new.name, tg_op);
      RETURN new;
  END IF;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Column 'id' is primary key on both tables so the above function fails as when there is an update on source as that record already exists on destination.

I tried to modify function to update rest of the columns in the table comparing the id fields on source and destination.

```
 Update des
      Set name = new.name,tg_op= update
      From destination des join source src
      ON des.id = src.id
      Where des.id = src.id
```

But couldn't get the syntax correct. Any help would be most appreciated.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.

Comment: You need to issue specific `CREATE TRIGGER` statement in order for the function to be treated as trigger function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out solution for my problem, Below is the answer.
  Create FUNCTION ins_functiontest() RETURNS trigger AS '
 BEGIN
  IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
   Update destination_table_name
       SET 
       name = new.name,
       Where id = new.id;

END IF;
 END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Answer (score -1):

I did something similar for my log tables. But I duplicate the colums. 1 set for the new.* to catch insert and update and a set for the old.* also for update and delete. Then inserted a serials primary key, the time and idtransaction, txid_current(). The only bullet proof is the serial. The idtransaction depend from wich server works. If you change pc, and it can happen in the lifetime of a db, it will start again the counter. But cannot happen that two transactions with same id have same time. But can happen two transaction at the same time. Expecially if you have several users. connected

Comment: Thanks jurhas for your reply. unfortunately in my scenario i can't duplicate the columns. I figured out solution for my problem. Posting the solution here in case someone might need it.
 Create FUNCTION ins_functiontest() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
 IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
  Update stg_auth_group 
       SET 
       name = new.name,
       Where id = new.id;

  END IF;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;